# Java multikeymap put-method

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to implement the put and get-methods for a multikeymap in Java with two keys pointing to a value. I have written the put-method like this:

```
public ValueType put(KeyTypeA key1, KeyTypeB key2, ValueType value) {

 HashMap<KeyTypeB, ValueType> mappi = outerMap.get(key1);
 ValueType oldvalue;
 if (mappi.containsKey(key2)) {
  oldvalue = mappi.get(key2);
 } else {
  oldvalue = null;
 }
```

However, when I test this method (I have initialized mappi properly as an instance of my own multikeymap-type) with

```
mappi.put("xxxxx", 13, "xxxxx");
```

I get a NullPointerException at

```
if (mappi.containsKey(key2)) {
```

What could cause the exception? In my class MultiKeyMap I initialize the multikeymap object in the constructor, so that should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not homework, you could use [MultiKeyMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html) from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/), instead of redoing it from scratch.

To answer your question, I suspect the fault lays in `HashMap<KeyTypeB, ValueType> mappi = outerMap.get(key1);`. If key1 has no value in `outerMap`, then `mappi` will be null, causing the `NullPointerException`